# Can you "Merge Down" in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Excel has a "Merge Across" function built in that allows you to highlight a range and then automatically merge all the cells in each row, but NOT merge the rows themselves (for reports, mostly).  Can you do the same on columns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Excel does not support "Merge Down" natively.  I wrote a macro for the function:

```
Sub MergeDown()

Dim i As Integer, NumCols As Integer, NumRows As Integer, _
    LocX As Integer, LocY As Integer

LocX = Selection.Column
LocY = Selection.Row
NumCols = Selection.Columns.Count
NumRows = Selection.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To NumCols
    Range(Cells(LocY, LocX + i - 1), Cells(LocY + NumRows - 1, _
        LocX + i - 1)).Select
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Selection.Merge
Next

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler: Exit Sub

End Sub
```

PS: You really should not merge cells as it makes it very difficult to work with the sheet.

Comment: Um???? 1)Should you ask and answer your own question like this? 2) You can just select a vertical range and go to merge cells????

Comment: Per the StackOverflow FAQ, it's supposedly encouraged:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/
I'd also like to point out your suggestion only allows merging a single vertical range.  My code duplicates the "Merge Across" functionality that is built into Excel for multiple vertical ranges in a selection.  This is a question I've seen asked a lot on Google, but could not find a solution.